# is it possible to write rules on instances rather than classes in drools?

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to write something like this with drools but I am not sure how to go about it.

I have the following :

```
MyData d = new MyData();
MyData d1 = new MyData();
d.setValue(10);
d1.setValue(10);
```

and this is the rule I would like to implement :

```
rule "data d value equals 10 "
when
    d.getValue()==10;
then
doSmthg();
end
```

if I were to change the LHS to

```
$d: MyData(Value ==10)
```

the doSmthg() would be executed twice.

**So is there a way to write the rule only about one instance instead of all the instances of the MyData class??**

PS: I need to insert both d and d1 in the kieSession because I have other rules that involve all the instances.

Comment: How is it supposed to know which instance to execute on? Write a rule targeting whatever-it-is that is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the specific instance in your rule. Or if both items are the same and you just want the rule to fire once for a given condition, you can insert a flag or other construct to keep it from firing multiple times.

For example, let's say that you have two MyData with value = 10. The one you do want to fire the rule also has a boolean flag latest = true.

So your working memory has:

```
MyData( value = 10, latest = true ) // we want to trigger the rule with this
MyData( value = 10, latest = false ) // and not this
```

Then we'd modify our rule to also check for the latest flag.

```
rule "Data value is 10, latest"
when
  $d: MyData( value == 10, latest == true )
then
  $d.doSmthg();
end
```

Alternatively if both objects are actually the same and there's nothing unique about them, and we just want to trigger based on the presence of a MyData with value 10, you have two ways to do this.

The first way is to use `exists` -- this just fires if there exists an instance in working memory that meets this criteria. As long as you never re-evaluate the rule by calling `update`, this should suit your needs. Note however that you have no reference to the object in this case.

```
rule "Any data value with 10 exists"
when
  exists( MyData(value == 10) )
then
  doSmthg(); // must be function or static import; cannot be instance method
end
```

If you do need to do work against the instance, you can't use exists and instead have to insert a flag or otherwise keep the rule from firing again. Easiest way is to insert something into working memory to act as a flag.

```
rule "Data value is 10, with flag"
when
  not( String(this == "DATA_10") ) // if flag does not exist in memory
  $d: MyData( value == 10 )
then
  $d.doSmthg();
  insert( "DATA_10" ); // insert flag
end
```

---

So to summarize, your options are:

1. Key off of a unique characteristic if possible
2. Use `exists` if you don't need an instance reference
3. Insert a flag or other flow control mechanism to keep the rule from firing a second time.